# StackExchange opserver: How to monitor SQL Server databases?

Tags: sql-server, iis, opserver

I have connected 4 my SQL servers using sa user.
On any of databases when I click on database to I receive the error 500

```
Error loading
Status: Internal Server Error
Code: 500
Url: sql/db/mydb/tables
```

Comment: It was a bug in opserver https://github.com/opserver/Opserver/issues/135 . Now it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug in opserver 
https://github.com/opserver/Opserver/issues/135

Now it is fixed.